# Remove new line if next line does not begin with `>`

Tags: bash

I want to delete a line break if the line does not start with a `>`. consider the text file `sequences.txt`

```
> Sequence 1
actg
tggc
> Sequence 2 
aacg
ggtt
```

I want it to be changed to

```
> Sequence 1
actgtggc
> Sequence 2 
aacgggtt
```

Comment: ... if it does not start with a `>` and if the succeeding line does not start with a `>` either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ok with `awk` could you please try following then(tested with provided samples only).

```
awk '
/^>/{
  if(value){
    print value
  }
  value=$0 ORS
  next
}
{
  value=(value?value:"")$0
}
END{
  if(value){
    print value
  }
}
'   Input_file
```

Comment: Nice! first time usink awk. Do you use the `>>` to write the content to a new file  or how do you do it?

Comment: @A.Dumas, you want to create a output file you could put it in last like `....Input_file  > Output_file` etc.